# Reverse Binary Numbers 4/8 test succeds

Tags: c#

My task is to  write a program for reversing numbers in binary. For instance, the binary representation of 13 is 1101, and reversing it gives 1011, which corresponds to number 11. Where the input contains a single line with an integer N, 1≤N≤1000000000.

I have to pass 8 tests, so far I've only passed 4/8. An input could be 13 where the expected is 11.

### Sample input

```
13
```

### Sample output

```
11
```

To clarify I do not get the output from the tests, only the results of them.

Any thoughts on how I can update the code?

```
public class Reversebinary
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        //Convert Decimal to binary
        int num;
        string binary, reversed;

        //Read integer value from console
        num = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        //Console.WriteLine(num);
        if (num > 1 && num < 1000000000)
        {
            //Convert the integer value to string binary
            binary = Convert.ToString(num, 2);

            //reverse string binary
            reversed = reverseString(binary);

            //Console.WriteLine("binary: " + binary);
            //Convert reversed string binary to int32 and print out
            Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToInt32(reversed, 2));
        }
        else
            Console.WriteLine("Number is not between 1 or 1000000000");


    }

    static string reverseString(string str)
    {
        return new string(str.Reverse().ToArray());
    }
}
```

EDIT1: clarification of the tests.

EDIT2: please understand I just want your opinion on the code so I can alter to it to succed the tests. I am not asking for you to provide me code.

EDIT3: Problem solved, I passed the tests after including greater/lesser or equals operator. Thanks for all your inputs.

Comment: What are the tests? Where does your output deviate? There are several things missing from this question. Is it a homework assignment?

Comment: *I have to pass 8 tests, so far i've only passed 4/8* This bit needs some clarification I think. What tests fail? You need to post some examples of input, expected output and actual output

Comment: You need to make sure you have a "try-catch" statement on "num = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());" because otherwise your program will crash whenever you give an input that isn't an integer

Comment: Well i do not get more information from the tests other than the results of them failing or not. The input is a number and the output is a number reversed in binary!

Comment: So, you don't know what numbers are being tested? You are only being told that you pass 4 out of 8 tests?

Comment: @Rariolu Ah! yes can't forget try-catch, thanks for the advice.

Comment: @JarrettRobertson Exactly, but this time i cleared the tests by including greater/lesser than or equal operator and i passed all the 8 tests. I guess i wasn't that far from problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At least, numbers are in 1≤N≤1000000000 and you are not considering 1 and 1000000000.

```
if (num >= 1 && num <= 1000000000)
        {
            //Convert the integer value to string binary
            binary = Convert.ToString(num, 2);

            //reverse string binary
            reversed = reverseString(binary);

            //Console.WriteLine("binary: " + binary);
            //Convert reversed string binary to int32 and print out
            Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToInt32(reversed, 2));
        }
```

Also, you can use `int.TryParse` instead of `int.Parse` to avoid exceptions. 
So your `if` condition should look like this

```
    int num = 0;
    if (int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out num) && num >= 1 && num <= 1000000000)
    {
         ...
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace Reversebinary
{
    class Reversebinary
    {
        static byte[] reverseBinary = new byte[] {0, 8, 4, 12, 2, 10, 6, 14, 1, 9, 5, 13, 3, 11, 7, 15 };  
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //Convert Decimal to binary
            int num;
            int reversed;

            //Read integer value from console
            num = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            if (num >= 0 && num <= 15)
            {

                //reverse string binary
                reversed = reverseBinary[num];

                Console.WriteLine(reversed.ToString("x2"));
            }
            else
                Console.WriteLine("Number is not between 0 and 15");

        }

    }
}
​
```